# How to submit events to InkCanvas in WPF manually?

Tags: wpf, inkcanvas

How would I be able to submit events manually to be received by InkCanvas ?

What I need to do, is to set the mode of InkCanvas to ink mode, and then, send virtual events to InkCanvas so that I get a drawing behavior as if user used the real mouse.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet shows an example of drawing a shape in InkCanvas:

```
StylusPointCollection stroke1Points = new StylusPointCollection();
stroke1Points.Add(new StylusPoint(50,10));
stroke1Points.Add(new StylusPoint(90,50));
stroke1Points.Add(new StylusPoint(10,50));
stroke1Points.Add(new StylusPoint(50,10));

Stroke stroke1 = new Stroke(stroke1Points);

canvas.Strokes.Add(stroke1);
```

Where **canvas** is of type **InkCanvas**. The above generates a triangle in the canvas.

---

*"And yes, you may accept the answer if it helps you."*

Comment: this is not what I want, what I want to use the freehand drawing that is built in the InkCanvas, which is activated at Ink mode, I want to achieve it without real mouse events, is this possible ?

Comment: If not mouse, where do the input come from??? Whatever the shape be, you have to know the points.

Comment: we have a dual pen board, connected via serial port, each pen streams coordinates, I need to pass those coordinates to a InkCanvas, using the built in freehand drawing.

Comment: That's exactly you can do with the above code. You can add the coordinates as stylus points to the stroke1 collection. If you detect a new stroke is being created, you can add a new StylusPointCollection as above.

Comment: Thanks loxxy, but the built in freehand drawing in InkCanvas is much faster than using StylusPointCollection.
I already tried the StylusPointCollection approach, it works well, but not as fast as freehand drawing at InkCanvas

Comment: You probably should have an sdk for that touch device. or you can read this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/11/04/introduction-to-wpf-4-multitouch.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    private void inkSurface_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        inkSurface.CaptureMouse();

        _inkStroke = new Stroke(
            e.StylusDevice.GetStylusPoints(inkSurface));
        _inkStroke.DrawingAttributes.Width = 5;
        _inkStroke.DrawingAttributes.Height = 5;
        _inkStroke.DrawingAttributes.Color = Colors.Black;

        inkSurface.Strokes.Add(_inkStroke);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void inkSurface_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_inkStroke != null)
        {
            _inkStroke.StylusPoints.Add(
                e.StylusDevice.GetStylusPoints(inkSurface));
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void inkSurface_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        inkSurface.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```